# Restrict box to one column

Tags: multicolumn, multicol, framed

I have this box created using `framed`. I have a one column format. As a result of which the box spans over entire column. I want to have two columns, such that this box occupies half of what it is occupying. I want to place these boxes side by side.

I tried using `multicol` package, but the figure does not appear after compilation. I am not sure why the figure disappears. I was wondering if we can control the dimensions of framed box or how can I make multicol properly. I did not find helpful queries or proper documentation about `framed`.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\footnotesize
    {\FrameSep1pt
    \begin{framed}\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{@{}l @{}}
\aquestion{}{Some text  }{a) }{b) B. }{c) C}{d) D}
\end{tabular}
\end{framed} }
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\twocolumn` followed by using `\onecolumn` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with the package tasks, it's ok for you.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tasks}
    \begin{document}

    Some Text
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task A
        \task B
        \task C
        \task D
    \end{tasks}
    \end{document}
```

[image]